# How to clear specific input field in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form. After getting a specific string from a jQuery Ajax request, I want to clear some input fields of a form by jQuery id selector. What should I do ?

My jQuery code:

```
    $.post(site_url.concat('xml_request/cert.php') , { special_code:special_code , cert_id_name:cert_id_name , recive_date:sector_dob5 , about_cert:about_cert } , function(data){


    $('#add_cert_feedback').html(data);

    if (data.indexOf('New Certificate is now Added') !== -1) {

        //Want to reset a Input field here

    } else {

        $('#the_heck').html('shit!');           
    }

    $.post(site_url.concat('xml_request/cert.php') , { special_code:'_get_array_cert' } , function(data){

        $('#cert_load').html(data);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below code to clear input field -

```
$('#inputId').val('');
```

I have used `id` selector, you can use `class` or any other selector for selecting `input` (as per your requirement) and set empty string in `.val('')` to clear its value.

Comment: Thanks! :-D @Bhushan kawadkar